# ASP.NET MVC - HtmlEncode all strings by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For example, a user creates a new question on a forum.

I send ajax to the server, then I use HtmlEncode to exclude the HTML code before saving it in the database.

Is it possible that HtmlEncode would be used automatically when receiving a request?

Also, when using the attribute (for example [HtmlAllowed]) you can allow html code in request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Yegor Androsov, for pointing me to right direction.

This ModelBinder automaticaly encode all string properties, except that has `[SafeHtml]` attribute

```
public class SafeStringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        string name = bindingContext.ModelName;
        string value = request.Unvalidated[name];

        Type holderType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        if (holderType != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyType = holderType.GetProperty(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);
            if (propertyType == null) return value;

            object[] attributes = propertyType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            bool hasAttribute = attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof (SafeHtmlAttribute));

            if (!hasAttribute && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SafeHtmlAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using custom model binder, every string property or string parameter will go through this method when ASP.NET attempts to bind request to parameters of action method

```
public class StringBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);

        var str = (string)value?.ConvertTo(typeof(string));

        str = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str);
        return str;
    }
}
```

And in `Application_Start()`

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new StringBinder());
```

Comment: This code throws an exception `HttpRequestValidationException` even with `[AllowHtml]` or `[ValidateInput(false)]`. 
Found a solution to use `Request.Unvalidated`

Comment: yeah, looks like my my input strings were already processed, so it went through binder fine. glad it helped to find correct solution. you might want to accept your own answer